# Bamboo artifacts

Tags: bamboo

I am very new to Bamboo. I have got a html file generated using log4j. I wish to put it in user-defined artifacts but don't know how.

It is in surefire-reports folder so I tried giving Source directory as `"**/target/surefire-reports/"` and Artifact Copy Pattern as `"**/*.html"` but it doesn't seems to work.

Any idea how to configure it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change copy pattern to

```
*.html
```

and verify your complete path.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to get all surefire reports from each module, so I created a new Artifact definition with:

- Name = Surefire Reports
- Location =
- Copy Pattern = */target/surefire-reports/*.*

This was using Bamboo 3.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

The Location field does not provide the [Ant file copy pattern](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html) feature, only a fixed path is accepted relative to the working directory.

Set the Location as

```
target/surefire-reports
```

and the Copy pattern as

```
**/*.html
```

Also make sure that the Shared checkbox is set, otherwise other jobs will not be able to download the artifact.